# how to use embedded tomcat in modular java project

Tags: java, tomcat

I wanna create a java modular project that has an internal tomcat server in it. I can easily use embedded tomcat server in non-modular java but web it comes to modules it has a lot of errors on it.
here is my module-info.java file

```
module RunMe{
    requires tomcat.embed.core;
    requires annotations.api;
}
```

and when just i run simplest tomcat server code it give me this:

```
Nov 12, 2019 10:08:26 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext setPath
WARNING: A context path must either be an empty string or start with a '/' and do not end with a '/'. The path [/] does not meet these criteria and has been changed to []
Nov 12, 2019 10:08:27 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8571"]
Nov 12, 2019 10:08:27 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Nov 12, 2019 10:08:27 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Tomcat]
Nov 12, 2019 10:08:27 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.11
Nov 12, 2019 10:08:27 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader startInternal
SEVERE: LifecycleException 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/instrument/IllegalClassFormatException
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:333)
    at tomcat.embed.core/org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.createClassLoader(WebappLoader.java:503)
    at tomcat.embed.core/org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.startInternal(WebappLoader.java:388)
    at tomcat.embed.core/org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at tomcat.embed.core/org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4955)
    at tomcat.embed.core/org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at tomcat.embed.core/org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429)
    at tomcat.embed.core/org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at tomcat.embed.core/org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
    at tomcat.embed.core/org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:944)
    at tomcat.embed.core/org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
    at tomcat.embed.core/org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at tomcat.embed.core/org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429)
    at tomcat.embed.core/org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at tomcat.embed.core/org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
    at tomcat.embed.core/org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:944)
    at tomcat.embed.core/org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:261)
    at tomcat.embed.core/org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at tomcat.embed.core/org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at tomcat.embed.core/org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at tomcat.embed.core/org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
    at tomcat.embed.core/org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at tomcat.embed.core/org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:370)
    at RunMe/test.RunMe.main(RunMe.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.instrument.IllegalClassFormatException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 29 more
```

Comment: Hi! Did you find any resolution for the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to resurrect an old question, but I don't see an answer.  Maybe this will help someone else down the line.

Add the following to your module-info.java file:

```
requires java.instrument;
```

Comment: Thanks for that. The answer really helped ;)